# OnPropertyChanged doesn't raise on SelectedValue

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I use the OnPropertyChanged method to find out when DPs in my ComboBox become there value, to filter the ItemsSource of the ComboBox based on the DPs.

```
  Select Case e.Property.Name
//Some Code
```

my problem is, that  the SelectedValueProperty doesn't raise the event the first time the control is loaded, i.e. when it becomes a value, only when the value was changed by user action is does raise.
any explanation or help for solving this problem please. or can someone give my an other way.

Answer (score 0):

Just handle the Loaded event.
You can even point it to the same event handler.

Comment: What have you tried?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx

Comment: i want to filter the list of my inherited ComboBox, by check the values of the DPs. its works fine for my own DPs, but for any reason, i will also check the SelectedValue, and their is a problem that the event doesn't fire the first time the SelectedValue was changed, i.e. when it becomes their value.